# Warning: DOMXPath::query() does not accept the syntax

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, xpathquery

I'm trying to extract a DOMDocument in PHP with the help of DOMXPath. With the website http://xpather.com/ I tried to find the correct query for my needs.

The query is the following:

`/*/* except /*/*[@id='test']`

What I try to achieve: In a DOM document, I need only the content of a container with the ID `test` in this case. Nothing else. In XPather the result looks good. No errors. Everything works as expected. But when I try this in my PHP application, I get the error from the title: `DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression`

My code:

```
$domDocument = $this->domParser->loadHTML($markup);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$nlist = $xpath->query("/*/* except /*/*[@id='test']");

if ($nlist != null) {
    $node = $nlist->item(0);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    $domDocument->saveHTML();
}
```

Where is the error here?

Comment: `except` is (I think) XPath 2 and unless things have changed - DOMXPath uses XPath 1.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is: `except` is XPath 2 and DOMXPath uses XPath1. So easy :)

The correct XPath1 query is the following: `"/*/*[not(@id='test')]"`

Thanks @Nigel Ren for your hint :)